# Determine if a fork is ready

Tags: github, github-api

From the documentation at https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/

```
Forking a Repository happens asynchronously. Therefore, you may have to 
wait a short period before accessing the git objects. If this takes longer than 
5 minutes, be sure to contact Support.
```

Is there a way to check if the fork is completed?

I thought about accessing individual files in the forked repo, but I don't have a large enough repo (that actually takes a long time to fork) to test this on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You reach out to GitHub support as well, so I'll paste my answer here.

---

That's a great question. Normally, forking should be done within seconds, but for larger repositories might take a while. One way to know when forking is done (via the API) is to fetch the list of commits for the fork:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository

If forking is not done yet, you should get back a 409 with this message:

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict

{
  "message": "Git Repository is empty.",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

When forking is done, you'll get back a 200 OK with a list of commits.

Comment: Is this still the recommended way to check for fork being ready? I also used a `since` param of current date so it doesnt take time get all the commits.

Comment: I  found more convenient to use GET /repos/:owner/:repo to verify fork existence. It looks way efficient that listing commits.